# How can i add white border after background color in Kivy via Pure Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

Below code works and i can clearly see the blue Color(0, 0.525, 0.953, 1) background of takim_isimleri_box BoxLayout
Base code:

```
from kivy.graphics import Color, RoundedRectangle, Line
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

takim_isimleri_box = BoxLayout()
with takim_isimleri_box.canvas.before:
    Color(0, 0.525, 0.953, 1)  # Background color 
    takim_isimleri_box.rect = RoundedRectangle(size=takim_isimleri_box.size, pos=takim_isimleri_box.pos, radius=[10, 10, 10, 10])

def update_rect2(instance, value):
    instance.rect.size = instance.size
    instance.rect.pos = instance.pos
takim_isimleri_box.bind(size=update_rect2, pos=update_rect2)
```

I want to add a white white border after background color in Kivy via Pure Python?
Howe can i do this?

What i tried, i asked it to Chatgpt it recommended me below code but did not worked.
ChatgPt:

```
from kivy.graphics import Color, RoundedRectangle, Line
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

takim_isimleri_box = BoxLayout()

with takim_isimleri_box.canvas.before:
    Color(0, 0.525, 0.953, 1)  # Background color 
    takim_isimleri_box.rect = RoundedRectangle(size=takim_isimleri_box.size, pos=takim_isimleri_box.pos, radius=[10, 10, 10, 10])

with takim_isimleri_box.canvas.after:
    Color(1, 1, 1, 1)  # White color for the border
    Line(rectangle=(takim_isimleri_box.x, takim_isimleri_box.y, takim_isimleri_box.width, takim_isimleri_box.height), width=1.5)

def update_rect2(instance, value):
    instance.rect.size = instance.size
    instance.rect.pos = instance.pos

takim_isimleri_box.bind(size=update_rect2, pos=update_rect2)
```

Above code did not work. There is no white border. I only see blue background without white border.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```py
import kivy
from kivy.graphics import Color, Line, RoundedRectangle
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        box = BoxLayout()
        with box.canvas:
            Color(0, 0, 1)
            RoundedRectangle(size=box.size, pos=box.pos)
            Color(1, 1, 1)
            Line(rectangle=[box.x, box.y, box.width, box.height], width=10)
        return box


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```